# Get remote webpage content by its IP address & HTTP Host header?

Tags: php

I would like to fetch the content of a webpage via its IP address. There are many other websites which also share this IP, hence the use of HTTP Host header.
This PHP web server has no DNS service and will respond to

```
file_get_contents("http://allaboutcircuits.com");
```

by

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

From several examples, I tried:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Host:allaboutcircuits.com')));
$url = 'http://68.233.243.63';
echo file_get_contents($url, 0, $context);
```

and it seems that I still have the same error **at the line of file_get_contents()**, meaning file_get_contents() still queries DNS for the Host header albeit the provided IP address.

How to I fix this code ?

Comment: Your question was migrated to [superuser](http://superuser.com/q/474370/123710).

Comment: That was slightly different. That question told him about using the Host header, but this question was prompted by the problem he ran into when trying to do what they advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the web site is responding with a redirect to `www.allaboutcircuits.com`, so PHP is trying to follow the redirect.  Change your Host header to include the `www.` prefix and it should work.

Comment: Oh my ! Thank you Barmar ! What can i say :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$s=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP); 
socket_connect($s,'68.233.243.63',80);
socket_send($s,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.allaboutcircuits.com\r\n\r\n",1000,0);
socket_recv($s, $buf, 100000,0);
socket_close($s);
echo $buf;
```

should be a start!

Comment: Just a typo - result is in $buf, not $res

Comment: After socket connection, How do we fetch webpage content ?